# Pentaho report designer bulk change file location in subreports

Tags: pentaho, report-designer

Currently using PRD: 5.2
I have a main report with 7 subreports. Each subreport has their own ktr file.
The subreports contain images also.

Let's say all the ktrs come from this location: 
C:\Users\NAME\Desktop\Evaluations(ktr filename here)

Is there a way to bulk change all these file locations(from all subreports) to another path?
So I would change: C:\Users\NAME\Desktop\Evaluations\comments.ktr
To for example: penatho\report\ktr\comments.ktr

But for all the files **&** images in all subreports at the same time.
Is this somehow doable or is there some main-setting that I overlooked to input a main path?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with the subreports, but in the PRPT files you can use environment variables. So, you can set the static part of the path with env variables and specify dinamically the KTR filename only.  See here if you help:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30781862/pentaho-5-3-how-to-read-a-property-in-prpt-files)